# xsl-fo how to put the characters in the revision-bar

Tags: xsl-fo

We have the needs to add a static area at the region-end and mark with some characters if the corresponding content in the region-body has some specific tags.

We want to display the character in the region-end and the content in the region-body at the same level. we can now only put a colored square using the revision-bar-style = "solid" and revision-bar-color in that location but how to put a character there instead of the colored square?

Could anyone suggest some way to get this purpose?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a change bar, you can use an fo:float that only appears if your conditions are satisfied. In the fo:float, you can put any text or graphics you want.
Specify float="right", width="1mm". Insert a block-container that has the right dimensions to display your text in the region-after.

Comment: Hi Hobbes, thank you for your reply. let me try this out.

Comment: Hi Hobbes, looks like the float is not for my case as I have contents in `table-cell[1]` which is full region-body height and I have to put the Character Markers which needs to be in `table-cell[2]` or `table-cell[3]` for the special content inside the `table-cell[1]`. Otherwise float is a very good idea to put things in wherever physical location.

Comment: Do the characters need to be at a specific height, lining up with a paragraph in table-cell[1]?

Comment: Yes, the characters in table-cell[2] or [3] has to be lining up with the special words in table-cell[1]. but I can get the physical height from the java method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AH Formatter, you can put an `fo:float` inside `fo:change-bar-begin`.  See https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf64/ahf-ext.html#fo.change-bar-begin

Comment: Thank you Tony, we are still using xsl version 1.0 but we are using AH Formatter. let me check this out.